# vSphere with Tanzu login as Kubernetes Cluster Admin in _supervisor_

Tags: vmware-vsphere

How to login as Tanzu's supervisor cluster admin?

I can login as vSphere administrator in the supervisor cluster (10.x.y.z) as shown next:

```
$ kubectl vsphere login --server=x10.x.y.z --insecure-skip-tls-verify

Username: administrator@vsphere.local
Password: 
Logged in successfully.
$ kubectl config set-context 10.x.y.z
Context "10.x.y.z" modified.
$ kubectl get wcpclusters -A
NAMESPACE   NAME    AGE
test1       test1   20d
test1       test2   20d
```

but the vSphere administrator doesn't have Kubernetes Cluster Admin rights in the supervisor, it cannot perform many actions for example listing the secrets of the supervisor cluster:

```
$ kubectl get secrets
Error from server (Forbidden): secrets is forbidden: User "sso:Administrator@vsphere.local" cannot list resource "secrets" in API group "" in the namespace "default"
```

I have searched a lot but only found instructions to login as kubernetes cluster administrator of the guests clusters. In my case I want to have these rights in the supervisor cluster instead.

Thanks